# multi module aggregation in maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis

i.  We need to generate class files from a wsdl file using axis 2 maven plugin.

ii. The issue is that both the files are in separate modules [aar module for wsdl file, srv module for java classes]

iii.    We are not able to refer the wsdl file from a separate module to generate the classes.

On adding the aar module as a dependancy to the srv module, we are not able to access the wsdl file placed in the aar module.

Please suggest a method to access the wsdl file from aar module and generate the java class files in the srv module.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Each module should have a separate pom.xml and there should ba a main(parent) pom.xml which linking all dependencies.

Comment: yes that is done, but the aar file does not come as a dependancy to the srv module. Also can you let me know any sample on how to refer the file from different module.

Comment: Can you show your parent and childern POM files please (Relevant portions only)